# Recorrer un un objeto con Vue2.js

Tags: json, laravel-5, array, vue.js, vuex

Mi pregunta es como accedo al array de parroquia...

intente en el HTML hacer:

`{{@beneficiario.parroquia.parroquia}}` y y da este error:

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'parroquia' of undefined"

**HTML**

#### JSON

```
            @{{ beneficiario.parroquia.parroquia}}
```

```
            @{{ $data }}
```

**JSON:**

```
   "beneficiario": {
    "id": 1,
    "cedula": "V-14748547",
    "nombres": "Pepito",
    "apellidos": "¨Pregunton",
    "email": "pepitopregunton@gmail.com",
    "telefono": "02128477447",
    "direccion": "La Palomera",
    "parroquia_id": 617,
    "parroquia": {
      "id": 617,
      "parroquia": "BARUTA",
      "municipio_id": 181,
      "municipio": {
        "id": 181,
        "municipio": "BARUTA",
        "estado_id": 13,
        "estado": {
          "id": 13,
          "estado": "MIRANDA",
          "activo": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "canaimas": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "modelo": "MG10T",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "activo": 1,
        "pivot": {
          "beneficiario_id": 1,
          "canaima_id": 1,
          "serial_canaima": "454DS5FDFD55",
          "descripcion": "esta rayada"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

y el VUE.js es:

```
 
    new Vue({
     el: "#beneficiario",
     data: {
      cedula: '',
      beneficiario: []
    },
    methods:{
      searchB: function(){
        var url = '../../getCedulaBeneficiario/' + this.cedula;
        axios.get(url).then(response => {
          this.beneficiario = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);
        });

      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

con te dije anteriormente... me pude guiar con tu respuesta.. hice esto!

declare una array para cada uno!..

```
new Vue({
 el: "#beneficiario",
 data: {
  cedula: '',
  beneficiario:[],
  parroquia:[],
  municipio:[],
  estado:[]
},
methods:{
  searchB: function(){
    var url = '../../getCedulaBeneficiario/' + this.cedula;
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
      this.beneficiario = response.data;
      this.parroquia = response.data.parroquia;
      this.municipio = response.data.parroquia.municipio;
      this.estado = response.data.parroquia.municipio.estado;
      console.log(response.data);
    });

  }
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Puedes acceder a los atributos del arreglo usando [ ]:

```
var nombre_parroquia = beneficiario[beneficiario[parroquia]];
```

Comment: con tu idea me pude guiar.. lo que hice fue esto y me Funciono!

Comment: genial! me alegra haberte ayudado.